# Removing spesific codename and dates from file names in python

Tags: python-3.x

[EDIT: picture. red boxses are the caracters i want to remove, i want to keep the green boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRAHC.png)

I got a bunch of files that I want to remove codename and dates from. See example

ORIGINAL FILE = BD **filename-i-want-to-keep** 2020 324 394.exe

ORIGINAL FILE = BD **filename-i-want-to-keep** 2020 327 342.exe

ORIGINAL FILE = BD **filename-i-want-to-keep** 2020 343 423.exe

This is the result I want

CHANGED FILE = **filename-i-want-to-keep**.exe

CHANGED FILE = **filename-i-want-to-keep**.exe

CHANGED FILE = **filename-i-want-to-keep**.exe

I tried to use OS to rename the files. But I guess I'm overlooking something..

```
import os

os.rename(r"C:\\**filename-i-want-to-keep*.exe",r"C:\\filename-i-want-to-keep.exe")
```

Comment: you should look to the module `re` that provide regex functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if I understood it wrong - so you have a bunch of files in a directory with file names of pattern that can be divided into four groups of "BD", "filename-i-want-to-keep", "2020 324 394", ".exe". And you're trying to rename it. 
So assuming you can iterate over the files in your directory, you can rename the files this way.

```
import re
import os

myregex = r'(.*)\s(.*)\s(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})(.*)' # or r'(BD)\s(.*)\s(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})(\.exe)'
myregex_compiled = re.compile(myregex)

for filename in os.listdir("/Users/vakell/Desktop/pythonregextest"):
    if myregex_compiled.match(filename):
        match = re.search(myregex, filename, re.IGNORECASE)
        os.rename(filename, match.group(2)+match.group(4))
```

Comment: i dont get the answer, is it possible to convert the filename to a string, slice it and print the new name?

Comment: @Kapa So what's happening is that we are searching for filenames that match the pattern you shared and it returns back substrings. In our case, filename is of the pattern `BD filename-i-want-to-keep 2020 324 394.exe`, which contains four sub strings from what you said, i.e `BD`, `filename-i-want-to-keep`, `2020 324 394`, `.exe`. Hence the regex `r'(.*)\s(.*)\s(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})(.*)'`.

Comment: @Kapa When we do a search on your filename using the regex I shared, it returns the 4 substrings I mentioned above. So I am simply concatenating the second & fourth match groups which contain `filename-i-want-to-keep` & `.exe` respectively.